# Multiple extra's in intent

Tags: android

I got three activities leading to same activity where a numbers is displayed and some calculations carried out depending where it came from, it was all going fine when I had only one extra in each intent, but lets say activity one I needed to know what option was selected so I added three more extra's.

But these three extra's I added in activity one don't seem to be recognized in the last activity.

Activity one

```
if (selectedItem.trim().equals("100mm")) {
    Total1 =  (int) (a * b * 10);
}

else if (selectedItem.trim().equals("215mm")) {
    Total2 =  (int) (a * b * 20);
}

else if (selectedItem.trim().equals("325")) {
     Total3 =  (int) (a * b * 30);
}
else if (selectedItem.trim().equals("hollow ")) {
     Total4 =  (int) (a * b * 10);
}
    Intent intent = new Intent(CalculateB.this,
            WlAmounts.class);
    intent.putExtra("Result100",Total1);
    intent.putExtra("Result215", Total2);
    intent.putExtra("Result325", Total3);
    intent.putExtra("ResultHollow",Total4);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Last activity

```
Intent sender = getIntent();
    int edge = sender.getExtras().getInt("Result100");
    int flat = sender.getExtras().getInt("Result215");
    int wide = sender.getExtras().getInt("Result325");
    int hollow = sender.getExtras().getInt("ResultHollow");
    int opes1 = sender.getExtras().getInt("ResultOpe1");
    int opes2 = sender.getExtras().getInt("ResultOpe2");

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("Result100")) {
        answer.setText(edge + "");



    } else if (getIntent().hasExtra("Result215")) {
        answer.setText(flat + "");

        //i'm doing some calculations here

    } else if (getIntent().hasExtra("Result325")) {
        answer.setText(wide + "");

    //i'm doing some calculations here

           } else if (getIntent().hasExtra("ResultHollow")) {
           answer.setText(hollow + "");

     //i'm doing some calculations here

          } else if (getIntent().hasExtra("ResultOpe1")) {
          answer.setText(opes1 + "");

    //i'm doing some calculations here

         }  else if (getIntent().hasExtra("ResultOpe2")) {
             answer.setText(opes2 + "");
```

Comment: What's your question? Any errors?

Comment: CAnt you do the calculations before sending the value? What happens with the new activity? Cause it seens thats will have only one value and that would be Total1 ou Total2 or Total3 or Total4. Is that it?

Comment: Why are result215 and result325 and resulthollow not being recognize when same code works for the rest of the extra's, i'v got a spinner on activity one with four options and now if I choose any of the last three options in getting all zero's displayed on last activity.

Comment: Well there is a number of calculations to be done with the number that come's threw, and the answer's to them are going to be displayed as well, so i taught be easier doing on last activity

Answer (score 1):

just keep one intent extra which will help identify which activity the call is coming from. then extract other respective intents

Comment: Hi i understand first part of you answer, could you explain then extract other respective intent a bit more, sorry i'm new to this

Comment: see your problem in LastActivity is which activity it came from. So if you pass a common intent from all the calling activities with different values, then in LastActivity you can do getIntent().getExtras().getInt("common",0). based on the value of this common parameter, you can identify the calling activity in LastActivity. After that, you can extract required parameters based on the common code.